# Airflow - Handle XCOM inside a loop

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have the following requirement.
A table consists of 10000 records. I need to get 1000 from it, do some processing and send to an HTTP endpoint. Then get the next 1000 and do the same. These 1000 chunks can be independently processed.
So I came up with the following DAG.

```
default_args = {
    "owner": "airflow",
    "depends_on_past": True,
    "wait_for_downstream":True,
    "max_active_runs":1,
    "start_date": datetime(2020, 10, 8),
    "catchup": False
}

dag = DAG("dag_id", default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=timedelta(1))

limit = 10000
cur_size = 0

while limit>cur_size:
    def get_records(**kwargs):
        ti = kwargs['ti']
        xcom = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='mysql_read_data_'+str(cur_size))
        data = [
            {
                "attributes": {
                    "att1": x,
                    "att2": y
                }
            }
            for x, y in xcom
        ]

        data = json.dumps(data)
    
        ti.xcom_push(key='data_to_cus_'+str(cur_size), value=data)

        return data



    mysql_read_data = MySQLReadOperator(dag=dag,
                                        mysql_conn_id='temper_flat_old',
                                        task_id='mysql_read_data_'+str(cur_size),
                                        params={'limit': 100, 'offset': cur_size},
                                        sql="sql/client_data.sql",
                                         trigger_rule="all_done",
                                         )


    python_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id='python_func_task_'+str(cur_size),
        dag=dag,
        python_callable=get_records,
        provide_context=True,
        trigger_rule="all_done",
    )

    send_to_endpoint = CustomOperator(
        dag=dag,
        task_id='custom_op_'+str(cur_size),
        data_xcom_task_id=python_task.task_id,
        data_xcom_key='data_to_cus_'+str(cur_size),
        trigger_rule="all_done",

    )


    mysql_read_data >> python_task >> send_to_endpoint

    cur_size += 1000
```

This works fine except for one thing. I'm doing pagination in this line `params={'limit': 100, 'offset': cur_size},` where `cur_size` is set by the iteration. But unfortunately, the second iteration has started before completing the first iteration's tasks. Then when I do xcom_pull inside `get_records()` the `cur_size` is a wrong one. And also in the         `data_xcom_key='data_to_kva_'+str(cur_size),`.

Either I need to prevent it from executing the next iteration till it fully finishes the current iteration or must have a way to correctly get the `task_id` to correctly push or pull from `xcom`
because now I get the error

> ERROR - 'NoneType' object is not iterable

The reason is task id I use to refer to pull form xcom is different

How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: `max_active_runs` is a DAG property, you need to define it in the DAG like `dag = DAG("dag_id", default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=timedelta(1), max_active_runs=1)`. `default_args ` handles arguments for tasks.

Comment: @PhilippJohannis Thanks. fixed it but still the issue exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main problem is the defining the function inside the while loop.  What happens is that Airflow renders the function every time it parses the file which normally happens every few minutes/seconds. The PyhtonOperator then calls the function regardless of the cur_size.

What you actually want is to pass an argument from the `PythonOperator` to the function, which you can do via `op_kwargs`:

```
def get_records(**kwargs):
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    xcom = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='mysql_read_data_'+str(kwargs['custom_cur_size']))
    data = [
        {
            "attributes": {
                "att1": x,
                "att2": y
            }
        }
        for x, y in xcom
    ]

    data = json.dumps(data)

    ti.xcom_push(key='data_to_cus_'+str(kwargs['custom_cur_size']), value=data)

    return data

while limit>cur_size:

    mysql_read_data = MySQLReadOperator(dag=dag,
                                        mysql_conn_id='temper_flat_old',
                                        task_id='mysql_read_data_'+str(cur_size),
                                        params={'limit': 100, 'offset': cur_size},
                                        sql="sql/client_data.sql",
                                         trigger_rule="all_done",
                                         )


    python_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id='python_func_task_'+str(cur_size),
        dag=dag,
        python_callable=get_records,
        provide_context=True,
        op_kwargs={'custom_cur_size': str(cur_size)},
        trigger_rule="all_done",
    )

    send_to_endpoint = CustomOperator(
        dag=dag,
        task_id='custom_op_'+str(cur_size),
        data_xcom_task_id=python_task.task_id,
        data_xcom_key='data_to_cus_'+str(cur_size),
        trigger_rule="all_done",

    )


    mysql_read_data >> python_task >> send_to_endpoint

    cur_size += 1000
```

Comment: Thanks, keeping the function inside the loop also worked, Sending it as a param worked.